# Rest or RestQL or Falcor or GraphQl

Tags: rest

I'm going to develop a web-application and planning to expose several APIs to customer. Also, going to consume several APIs from third party system

Rest or RestQL or Falcor or GraphQl

Which one would be the best choice of the above 4???

Thanks.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic, this might generate answers solely on opinions checkout https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: There's a nice video from Chris Hawkes comparing those 3: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OeUGswoYrvA

Comment: Thanks for the video. It answers my question.